# How to show a progress bar on screen programatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have a class named *BookAdder*. It extends *AsyncTask* and it should add a list of books on the app. Also some activities call it and I want to show a progress bar on center of screen when it is called.

Now, I don't know how can show a progress bar without it defines in XML file of activities?
Are there any way to create a progress bar then add it for showing or not?

Thanks

Comment: you can use ProgressDialog to achieve this requirement.

Comment: I want use a progressBar that show amount of added volume. Also ProgressDialog was avoided by Android website.

Comment: you can create progress bar dynamically

Comment: How come? I don't know what should I do exactly?

Comment: ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);.and add this object of progress bar to your layout

Comment: @PiyushGupta I don't access layout directly, I want to make and use it in a AsynTask class!

Comment: but after all create in Asynctask to display it you need to add it some where..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    new asyncTask(Your_context).execute();


    private class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> 
    {
        Context context;
        ProgressDialog pd;

        asyncTask(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context; 
            pd = new ProgressDialog(activityContext);
        } 
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            pd.setTitle("Loading..");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait ...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        } 
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
        {
                   // Update your UI. 
            if(pd.isShowing()) pd.dismiss();
        } 

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
               // Get all data from web.
        }

@Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) 
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            pd.setMessage("Please Wait..." + values[0].toString());
        }

        public class Progress 
        {
            public asyncTask task;

            public Progress(asyncTask task) 
            {
                this.task = task;
            }

            public void publish(String value) 
            {
                task.publishProgress(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Try to call progress update with `publishProgress(updating_values);`

Comment: As I told on upper comments, I don't want to use ProgressDialog. it was avoided by Android official website.

Comment: You can update your download progress. see my updated answer @omidnazifi

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
new DownloadData(yourClass.this).execute();


public class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
  ProgressBar pBar;
  Context context;

    public DownloadData(context con)
    {
            context = con;
             pBar = new ProgressBar(context);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);
            layout.addView(pBar);
            pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackgroud(Void.. params)
    {
        // download data
    }


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (pBar!=null) {
        ((LinearLayout)pBar.getParent()).removeView(pBar);
    }
}
}
```